# How to make swipe between components?

Tags: android, kotlin, swipe, android-architecture-components

I newbie in programming. I maked bottom bar navigation for fragments and now I wanna make swipe transition between NestedScrollViews that in component navigation. How can I make this?

----MainActivity----

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_screen) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController

        binding.mainNavigation.setupWithNavController(navController)

    }




}
```

----activity_main----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/helper_on_primary"
        app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="true"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/main_navigation" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/main_screen"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried to use ViewPager2 with fragments(NestedScrollView), but I didn't understand how to use it.

Comment: As per the [Material guidelines](https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-bar/guidelines#f2fb63e1-cc22-4853-acf6-b345e340fc47): "Don’t allow people to change destinations with a swipe gesture." - you shouldn't be using a bottom navigation bar at all if you want a swipe gesture between pages - that behavior is exclusively used for [tabs](https://m3.material.io/components/tabs/overview).

Comment: Use tablayout instead.